# Develop a restful service using WCF over Mono

Tags: macos, rest, mono, xamarin

I've been trying to create a WebApp that expose a Restful service with no success.

I'm using an iMac with Xamarin Studio as the IDE.

I successfully created an interface and the class that implements the service, and using a console application I can successfully bind the service and use, but I can't use a desktop application.

I need to deploy this as a web application on an IIS on a customer's server. I've been trying to do the binding in the **web.config** XML with no success.

thanks for your help

Comment: You usually need XSP to host the WCF service. Did you install XSP and try it out? Besides, if the target machine is Windows Server with IIS, you should use Windows with IIS as your development box. You should not expect XSP to be the same as IIS.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a more portable and reliable solution than using ASP .net with Apache (XSP), you can implement the FastCGI protocol on your mono project, create your RESTful service with it under a Windows Service, and then you can run it through mono-service.

Lastly, with this solution you can use your service with ANY server which implements FastCGI (Apache, nginx, Lighthttpd) and in any OS (if you don't do native calls, of course).

I did that by myself with nginx and I'm getting faster responses than using IIS/.net for dynamic code (you don't have all the ASP .net overhead which is unnecesary for a REST service).

Here you have an implementation of FastCGI for .net, it works flawlessly in mono: https://github.com/mzabani/FastCgiNet

One annotation, if you use the previous library, it has a bug with large files (it stores all the file in memory) but it's easily solved.